# Determining Whether a Collision is Elastic or Inelastic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

I am having a lot of trouble with this problem. [image]

The answer key says that the collision is inelastic, but I am not sure how they came to this conclusion given that there is no indication of whether the final speed is different from the original. Perhaps it has something to do with the new velocity vector? Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the problems in terms of momentum, and the individual vertical and horizontal components of their motion. Both the objects are traveling to the right, and conservation of momentum says that the sum of their momentum vectors will be the same after the collision, no matter how elastic or inelastic.

This means that their rightwards velocity will not be affected by the collision. The horizontal component of the vector will not change. They are both moving to the right, so the sum of their momentum vectors still be moving toward the right.

The reason the collision is **inelastic** is because even though they are moving to the right in the same direction, one is moving up and the other is moving down. If the collision were perfectly elastic they would bounce back and the angle of reflection would be equal to the angle of incidence. But after the collision their **vertical** velocity components are reduced by an **inelastic** collision. So they move less far up/down for the same amount they travel horizontally. This makes the angle of reflection **less** than the angle of incidence.